# Kids’ book I read in the ‘70s about a family of wizards, older siblings stronger than younger ones, something about cold steel and dragons?

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

When I was a kid in the ‘70s there was a book I really liked about a family of wizards —- the way magic worked was that you got stronger as you got older so the older siblings were more proficient and could cast more powerful spells.  Also cold steel had special powers in this universe, and dragons were antagonists.  I cannot remember the title of this book for the life of me and have looked for it in vain for decades.  Any help much appreciated!